# google app engine service unavailable

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm was following http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/ tutorial to create new Google App Engine project. It throws me an error as per below when I try to run the from my local host, but when    I deployed it working fine. (http://mynewcloudcom.appspot.com/). Please help.

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
Powered by Jetty://
```

Eclipse Console

```
Mar 05, 2012 10:42:46 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Mar 05, 2012 10:42:46 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\DontEditProject\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Mar 05, 2012 10:42:46 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Smartag_Eclipse_Project\DontEditProject\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Mar 05, 2012 6:42:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Mar 05, 2012 6:42:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. I need to run in JDK1.6. Once i changed the Java Compiler(right click project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> (Check) Enable project specific settings -> change the Compiler compliance level), its works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I justed changed the port from 8888 to 80 in the Debug Configuration and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
for me the problem was one of my filters had an exception. specifically objectify - it was not loaded properly. you can delete the filter and see if that's it

Comment: how did you delete this filter? (I'm new to app engine)

Comment: To temporarily delete the filter, edit web.xml, comment out `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>`

Answer (score 1):

When using `Java 1.7`, also check for the Execution Environment and set it to `JavaSE-1.7`.

You can look into the Execution Environment in:

`Right Click` -> `Properties` -> `Java Compiler`

And you have the option above `Restore Defaults` and `Apply`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by selecting "Automatically select an unused port" in run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens there is a "hanging" process that blocks the port. Therefore changing port in Run configuration helps, as well as checking "Automatically select an unused port" in run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me too. In my case, I had Run the project and due to some error in my code, the Project ran with errors. So, I debugged it and Run it again but without cancelling the earlier one in the console and it gave me that error. After cancelling or stopping the Project, it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. Seems that Plugin is stocked on creating and opening the socket for the server. i don't really know why happens, I've resolved in this way.

1. Open Run Configurations.
2. Open Server tab. Change the Embedded server Port.
3. Open Arguments tab.

   3.1 - VM arguments box. i've deleted all that stuff there and just let this 
   line and save changes and run it.

> -Xmx512m -javaagent:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar

It has worked pretty good 4me.
**If someone know which events or configuration change are the reason for . please let us know it**

NOTE: "*I'm not responsible for unexpected behave. I'm don't know if there is side effects ahead*"

Answer (score 0):

The solution working for me is to run appEngineServer from command line using Gradle, as comments in generated build.xml for endpoints module proposes. And gradle config includes option for Java 1.7 compatibility, so it's no reason to use Java 1.6 if You want 1.7:

**gradlew modulename:appengineRun**

> Currently, the appengine gradle plugin's appengine devappserver
>   launch doesn't interact well with Intellij/AndroidStudio's
>   Gradle integration.  As a temporary solution, please launch from the command
>   line. ./gradlew modulename:appengineRun

Answer (score 0):

I had a condition where a servlet defined in the web.xml with non existent class name. I specified proper class name, worked!