# Google Cloud Platform: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, jetty

I am learning Java and Google App Engine.
I am trying to implement the service described in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIIgcIqoPw

But when I am trying to run the project I am getting below error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
  Problem accessing /. Reason: 
  SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Powered by Jetty://
```

I tried to find on the web. Seems like it is some install issue. But I am not able to get a straight answer what I should do to fix this. Or may be I am not understanding the solution provided.

I will really be thankfull if you guys help me out.

Here is what I think is the error msg the console:

```
WARNING: EXCEPTION   
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nil.test.HelloAppEngine  
.  
.  
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable  
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the tutorials here: https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/ instead of that video which is 4 years old now and the tools have been changed since then, i.e. the new Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin is recommended over the legacy Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks @Andras, for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution here:
[google app engine service unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565273/google-app-engine-service-unavailable)

"*Found the answer. I need to run in JDK1.6. Once i changed the Java Compiler(right click project -> properties -> Java Compiler -> (Check) Enable project specific settings -> change the Compiler compliance level), its works fine now. Thanks.*"